# Drawing text in a NSButton subclass - positioning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawing, custom-controls

I Have a custom button:
[My Button http://cld.ly/29ubq](http://cld.ly/29ubq)

And I need the text to be centered, here's my code:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style =
    [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[style setAlignment:NSLeftTextAlignment];
att = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
           style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, 
           [NSColor blackColor],
           NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[style release];
// other Drawing code here
[[self title] drawInRect:[self bounds] withAttributes:att];
```

How do I center the text in the center of my button (not center of the bounds)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to get the size of the title first using `NSString -sizeWithAttributes:`. Then you can use that size to adjust the drawing of title within your bounds.

There is a trick to this, since you will almost always wind up dividing by two at some point in this process. When you do that, you may wind up with a half-pixel result, which Cocoa will happily use. However, it will cause your text to be blurry. You almost always want to call `floor()` on your coordinates before drawing on them to get yourself back onto integral pixels.

Edit: A basic example of centering (this should compile correctly, I haven't compiled it and my recent work has been over on iPhone which is upside-down):

```
NSRect rect;
rect.size = [[self title] sizeWithAttributes:att];
rect.origin.x = floor( NSMidX([self bounds]) - rect.size.width / 2 );
rect.origin.y = floor( NSMidY([self bounds]) - rect.size.height / 2 );
[[self title] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:att];
```

Anyway, something along those lines. You may want to offset a bit because of how your button draws, but this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could be interested in [Setting a Button’s Image](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Tasks/SettingButtonImage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000088-BAJBCGCG), which also explain how to position the title relative to the button’s image.

Comment: I want to try having no images... and I'd like to fill the button